# Get values out of sub lists in data frame

Tags: pandas, list

I want to remove the list type in my pandas data frame. So far every string is in a list. I want to keep the string and remove the list. Thank you[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```py
df.filter('decision') = df.filter('decision').applymap(lambda lst: eval(lst)[0])

# or

cols = ['decision1 category', 'decision2 category', 'decision3 category']
df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(lambda lst: eval(lst)[0])
```

Comment: I used: V1 = V1.applymap(lambda lst: lst[0]) and as a result all I get per row is: [      the data frame has more columns that the ones shown is this the reason why it is not working?

Comment: @LEONIELAMBERTZ How about `df = df.applymap(lambda lst: pd.eval(lst)[0])`

Comment: Than I get the error: NumExpr 2 does not support Unicode as a dtype

Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: @LEONIELAMBERTZ How about change `pd.eval` to `eval` or `ast.literal_eval`?

Comment: for eval I get this error: 'int' object is not subscriptable.    for art.literal_eval I get this error: name 'ast' is not defined

Comment: @LEONIELAMBERTZ I updated the answer. I guess the problem is that your dataframe not only has these three columns.